# Is it possible to have a multi-module pom as a module of a parent multi-module pom?

Tags: java, maven-2, build, build-process

The required structure is like this

Projects/pom.xml
Projects/parent1/pom.xml
Projects/parent2/pom.xml
Projects/parent2/child1/pom.xml
Projects/parent2/child2/pom.xml

- parent1 and parent2 are module of Projects/pom.xml
- child1 and child2 are modules of parent2
- The packaging type of parent2/pom.xml is pom.
- I have not used the parent tag in the child poms

If I call the parent poms then child1 and child2 are built correctly. The projects/pom.xml exists just as a collector to build all the parent projects.

When I run **mvn clean -pl parent2** child1 and child2 are not even recognized. Is this the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible certainly. Have a look at [this example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-module-enterprise) in the Sonatype maven reference book.

Without seeing the pom files, I'm afraid we will not be able to help you much further. Can you post them?